# cycle.js How to select element from instance of component

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

With cycle.js I am trying to create a reusable component that can exist multiple times of the page, including event handlers.

When using `DOMSource.select` it seems to be matching on the entire app container. Is there a way I can `.select` from only my (this instance of the component's) sub elements?

Comment: This sort of question might be better suited for https://gitter.im/cyclejs/cyclejs Here people expect to see what code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single component or just a few, isolate() mentioned by tm1rbrt works well and is simple to use.

If you have a large list of objects to render as components, especially if you have to update that list, try out cycle.js collections: https://github.com/cyclejs/collection

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use [isolate()](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/tree/master/isolate). It's somewhat similar to every Iterable item in react needing a `key` attribute.